# Numerical Analysis: Bisection method proof

Tags: numerical-methods

> Prove that $C_{n+1} - C_n = 2^{-n-2}(B_0 - A_0)$ where $C_n$ is the $n^{th}$ computed value of $C$ in the bisection method.

Not really sure where to start.

Comment: I think that you're missing some absolute value signs.

Comment: That's exactly how the question is asked, no absolute value signs.

Comment: What are $A_0,B_0$ and what is $C$ ?

Comment: Without an absolute value, the statement is indeed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: (1) $B_0-A_0$ is the length of the original interval.  (2) The length of the interval is cut in half (*i.e.*, multiplied by $2^{-1}$) on every iteration.  (3) $C_0 = (A_0+B_0)/2$. (4) The length of the $n^{th}$ interval is $|C_{n-1} - C_{n-2}|$, where I am counting $[A_0,B_0]$ as the first interval.